# Laravel/twitter-bootstrap website load automatically external sources

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-4, holder.js

I have build a page in Laravel 4 and twitter-bootstrap. When I refresh my `localhost` it takes a long time to load.
When I open my firefox inspector, under the tab `network` i see that my page load several external sources:

```
1- https://static.dreamsadnetwork.com/firefoxapp/quicking/contentScript.js
2- https://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=rulthun&CTID=ffqt
3- http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_preloader.jsp?dlsource=rulthun&CTID=ffqt&ver=13.1.4.44
```

With this external sources my page is very slow, Are those pages required to run my page properly? I also use `holder.js`.

And if not, how can I prevent that those pages load?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you that these links have nothing to do with either Laravel or Bootstrap. You should figure out which app/plugin/whatever loads these files, and remove those.

You can do that by checking the link in your inspector. In chrome, you can see this under the tab network, and then initiator. There you'll find: `file.js:15` where the number is the line in the code where the files are executed.

Comment: okay, this is weird, in my chrome browser, my page dont load any sources from above?, Is it possible that firefox load them?

Comment: That is very strange indeed. The only thing I can think of is that a Firefox plugin loads these pages, but still it would be weird that they aren't loaded on any other pages. Also: Firefox has an inspector like Chrome too, so you can try the same method there.

Comment: I have removed all my plugins/add-ons from firefox. The problem is over. Thanks for your suggestions!